# Number of distinct labeled trees

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am asked to find the number of distinct trees with vertex labeled from the set $\{1\cdots n\}$. In this case, I am given the restriction $n = 5$, but with the aditional condition that there must be $3$ vertex of degree $1$. Here is my attempt:

Since it is a tree, there are $4 = 5 - 1$ edges, therefore $4\cdot2 = 3 \cdot 1 + d_1 + d_2$, where $d_1, d_2$ are the degrees of the remaining two vertex. It is obvious that those degrees have to be $2$ and $3$. I have tried all posibilities regarding the conexion of the vertex of degree $1$, and I found out that the only possibility is that two of those vertex of degree 1 have to be connected to the same vertex, and that vertex has to be connected to another one of degree two (and therefore it has degree 3), and this last one with the remaining one-degree-vertex.

For those two one-degree-vertex, there are $5 \choose 2$ options to choose the label, since they represent actually the same, and therefore order does not matter. For the other vertex, since they are clearly distinguishable, there are $3!$ options $\Rightarrow $ there are $6 {5 \choose 2} = 60 $ options. Is my reasoning right?